# Batched writes (for denormalized data) in Firebase Realtime Database using Flutter?

Tags: flutter, firebase-realtime-database

Looking for the equivalent of ref.updateChildValues which is used in Swift, but for Flutter.

I have denormalised data in the Realtime Database, so looking to update data in a batch across specific child nodes.

Would appreciate any guidance! Thank you!

Comment: Can you explain more? Add more expectations? This is more of an opinion based question

Answer (score 2):

In Flutter that method is called [`update`](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_database/latest/firebase_database/DatabaseReference/update.html), same as in Firebase's web SDK. Just like in the iOS version, you pass in a `Map<String, dynamic>` with  the values to update. The keys in this map being the name/path of each location to update, and the values then being the value to write to that location.